# Unattended file is overriding pre staged domain joining options

Tags: powershell, wds

I am adding automatically created virtual machines as pre staged devices on our WDS and giving them full join rights

`New-WdsClient -DeviceId $macAddress -DeviceName $name -BootImagePath "Boot\x64\Images\boot.wim" -JoinRights Full -Domain "sievolab.int" -JoinDomain $true -OU $serverOU -User "$($env:UserDomain)\$($env:username)" -PxePromptPolicy NoPrompt -WdsClientUnattend "WdsClientUnattend\labbuildslave.xml" -ReferralServer $wdsServer`

This works great when installing manually but I recently started implementing the two unattended files so that we could have 100% automatic installations. Thing is if I don't join the domain in the ImageUnattend file it will not join the domain at all.

Is there a way of not specifying the domain/OU in the Unattended files and just use the rights given at prestage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the answer file with Windows System Image Manager under 4 specialize -> Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin -> Identification set UnsecureJoin to true.

I'm still specifying the domain explicitly, but it can be propably removed and be left up to the powershell command. I suspect this because I am not setting the MachineObjectOu and that is still setting correctly.